# How to do assignment in Pandas without warning?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to port this code in R to Python using Pandas.

This is my R code (assume data is a `data.frame`):

```
transform <- function(data) {
    baseValue <- data$baseValue

    na.base.value <- is.na(baseValue)
    baseValue[na.base.value] <- 1

    zero.base.value <- baseValue == 0
    baseValue[zero.base.value] <- 1

    data$adjustedBaseValue <- data$baseRatio * baseValue

    baseValue[na.base.value] <- -1
    baseValue[zero.base.value] <- 0
    data$baseValue <- baseValue

    return(data)
}
```

This is my attempt to port the R code in Python (assume data is `pandas.DataFrame`):

```
import pandas as pd

def transform(data):
    base_value = data['baseValue']

    na_base_value = base_value.isnull()
    base_value.loc[na_base_value] = 1

    zero_base_value = base_value == 0
    base_value.loc[zero_base_value] = 1

    data['adjustedBaseValue'] = data['baseRatio'] * base_value

    base_value.loc[na_base_value] = -1
    base_value.loc[zero_base_value] = 0

    return data
```

But then I got this warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

I have read through and don't understand how to fix it. What should I do to fix the code so that there is no more warning? I don't want to suppress the warning though.

Comment: Change `base_value = data['baseValue']` to `base_value = data['baseValue'].copy()`

Comment: Are you intending to modify the same `data` object?  Or do you want to return a copy?

Comment: @ayhan: That sounds like it'd just make the code silently wrong instead of wrong with a warning. Parts like the modification of `base_value` after the assignment to `data['adjustedBaseValue']` seem to indicate that the intent is to have `base_value` changes reflected in `data`.

Comment: @user2357112 In R, AFAIK, that assignment returns a copy. So the original dataframe wouldn't change as well. It seems like OP is using the returning copy to modify another series.

Comment: @user2357112 you absolutely can have an externally visible effect.  That warning is about working with dataframes that are deemed to be slices of other dataframes.  You aren't masking a problem when you set a copy.  You are just unlinking the data you're manipulating from the reference data.

Comment: @piRSquared: If you're going to work with a copy, why would you set `base_value.loc[na_base_value] = -1` and `base_value.loc[zero_base_value] = 0`? `base_value` isn't returned, and those lines show up after the last direct modification of `data`.

Comment: Yes, I would like to return the same `data` object, because I don't see any reason to copy the `data`.

Comment: @user2357112 I just replicated the actions in your function.  I'm not asking why OP made those assignments, I'm just providing the correct syntax to do so

Comment: @user2357112 You are correct. In R it is a [copy](http://i.imgur.com/sznxA1Y.png) but what I failed to notice was the OP is assigning  `data$baseValue <- baseValue` at the end of the R code.

Comment: Then you'll want to choose option 1, where you use `.loc` on the passed `data` object to avoid the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.  In the example, `base_value = data['baseValue']` sets up the copy.  Later you try to assign to it.  `base_value.loc[na_base_value] = 1`.  Instead you can assign directly to `data` like `data.loc[na_base_value, 'baseValue'] = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the same object that was passed to the function, then this should work so long as what's passed in as `data` isn't already a view of another dataframe.

```
def transform(data):
    base_value = data['baseValue']

    na_base_value = base_value.isnull()
    data.loc[na_base_value, 'baseValue'] = 1

    zero_base_value = base_value == 0
    data.loc[zero_base_value, 'baseValue'] = 1

    data['adjustedBaseValue'] = data['baseRatio'] * base_value

    data.loc[na_base_value, 'baseValue'] = -1
    data.loc[zero_base_value, 'baseValue'] = 0

    return data
```

If you want to work with a copy and return that manipulated copied data then this is your answer.

```
def transform(data):
    data = data.copy()

    base_value = data['baseValue'].copy()

    na_base_value = base_value.isnull()
    base_value.loc[na_base_value] = 1

    zero_base_value = base_value == 0
    base_value.loc[zero_base_value] = 1

    data['adjustedBaseValue'] = data['baseValue'] * base_value

    base_value.loc[na_base_value] = -1
    base_value.loc[zero_base_value] = 0

    return data
```

Comment: The second code snippet doesn't seem to "return that manipulated copied data". It returns the original `data` object, with only some of the manipulations applied.

Comment: Fixed, this code has several things that I'd change.  I added syntax that minimizes the changing of existing code.